# Making React aware of the custom configured CDN headers

Tags: reactjs, http-headers

Our React app is served from a static hosting using `S3` and `CloudFront`.

We configured `S3` and `CloudFront` to add `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` in the return header of each request made to resources in it. So for instance, our `index.html` makes a call to get the `.js` bundle from `CloudFront`, the returned header would include: `cloudfront-viewer-country: US` in my case.

My goal is to have the `React` app "wake up to life" already knowing the location of its user. I realize I can probably add some `javascript` to the `index.html` to keep/store it somehow so that the `React` root component can pick up on that and pass it on to wherever it needs to be (probably the redux state). But then I ask myself, how do I tap into the response header received when the `<script>` tag finished loading the bundle in order to extract the custom header from it?

the `index.html` is pretty straightforward. Its `body` looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div id=root></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/myBundle.ac9cf87295a8f1239929.js"></script>
</body>
```

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to access the headers from the page load or script load. You will have to make a separate request to access the headers.

You could also use browser's locale (`navigator.languages`) if you need this information for localization.

Comment: What if I force this information into a Cookie returned by the CloudFront (via a Lambda function I use to put the required header)?

Comment: @JasonGenX It is possible to access cookies with `document.cookie`. That will require you to add a cookie notice for visitors from EU, though.

Comment: Worth a try. The `navigator.languages` is a choice that can be altered easily. I need to know where people are from -- and yes, I know you can circumvent that with a VPN, but it's harder than faking your locale settings.

Comment: @JasonGenX Anything on the client side can be tampered with. You should have an API to serve the geolocation data and also check on the back end.

Comment: Naturally and I do have that, but I wanted to record the CloudFront "Country" property as well and stumbled into the unreachable-headers block. Resolving this is more of a technical challenge than an actual requirement. I already have a backend location endpoint serving a 3rd party IP -> Location data.